# Rails YAML and ActiveRecord-Serialization: !ruby/object:Blog <=> !ruby/ActiveRecord:Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, activerecord, yaml, delayed-job

Im running RVM together with bundler and im having trouble with my development environment:

- Rails 3.0.10
- ruby 1.9.2p180
- bundler 1.1.0

When running

```
rails c

y Blog.first
--- !ruby/object:Blog
attributes: [...]
```

which is clearly wrong. I expect this behavior:

```
bundle exec rails c

y Blog.first
--- !ruby/ActiveRecord:Blog
attributes: [...]
```

There seems to be a mixup with the dependencies or something, because even if i add an initializer like this:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_yaml_type
    "ruby/ActiveRecord:#{self.class}"
  end
end
```

it will be ignored when running rails without `bundle exec`.

This is very annoying because my IDE has no option to run the webserver in the context of bundle so, e.g. delayed_job, fails all the time when working with yaml-output.

Answer (score 0):

In which of files you add lines with `to_yaml_type`?
Try to put them into `config/environment.rb`.

And one more.
Parser can eat first letter in this line without exclamation point at the beginning:

```
"ruby/ActiveRecord:#{self.class}"
```